# how to align the columns properly in DynamicReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper, dynamic-reports

I am using DynamicReports to design reports to PDF.Here i am using `ComponentColumnBuilder`and `HorizantalList` and `VerticalList`.I am able to display them as columns with fixed widths.which is shown as below

[image]

My code is as follows

```
JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();//a new report
        StyleBuilder plainStyle = stl.style().setFontName("FreeUniversal");
        StyleBuilder boldStyle = stl.style(plainStyle).bold().setBorder(stl.pen1Point());
        StyleBuilder col1style = stl.style().setLeftBorder(stl.pen1Point());
        StyleBuilder col2style = stl.style().setLeftBorder(stl.pen1Point()).setBottomBorder(stl.pen1Point());
        StyleBuilder col3style = stl.style().bold().setBottomBorder(stl.pen1Point()).setLeftBorder(stl.pen1Point());

        VerticalListBuilder companyList = cmp.verticalList();
        companyList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text(field("companyName", type.stringType()))).setStyle(col1style));
        companyList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text(field("branchLocationAddress", type.stringType()))).setStyle(col1style));
        companyList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text("Mobile Number:")).add(cmp.text(field("mobileNumber", type.stringType()))).setStyle(col1style));
        companyList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text("Phone Number:")).add(cmp.text(field("landLineNumber", type.stringType()))).setStyle(col1style));
        companyList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text("Email:")).add(cmp.text(field("emailID", type.stringType()))).setStyle(col2style));
        companyList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text(field("OrganizationName", type.stringType()))).setStyle(col1style));
        companyList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text(field("DeliveryAddress", type.stringType()))).setStyle(col1style).setFixedHeight(30));
        companyList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text("Contact Number:")).add(cmp.text(field("PhoneNo", type.stringType()))).setStyle(col2style));
        companyList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text("Works Address:Same as Above")).setStyle(col3style).setFixedHeight(40));
        ComponentColumnBuilder nameColumn = col.componentColumn("", companyList).setFixedWidth(275);

        VerticalListBuilder receivingList = cmp.verticalList();
        receivingList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text("Invoice No")).setStyle(col1style));
        receivingList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text(field("InvoiceNo", type.stringType()))).setStyle(col2style));
        receivingList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text("Delivery Note")).setStyle(col1style));
        receivingList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text(field("DeliveryNote", type.stringType()))).setStyle(col2style));
        receivingList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text("Esugam NO")).setStyle(col1style));
        receivingList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text(field("EsugamNo", type.stringType()))).setStyle(col2style));
        receivingList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text("Buyer Order NO")).setStyle(col1style));
        receivingList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text(field("BuyerOrderNo", type.stringType()))).setStyle(col2style));
        receivingList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text("Dispatch Document NO")).setStyle(col1style));
        receivingList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text(field("DispatchDocumentNo", type.stringType()))).setStyle(col2style));
        receivingList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text("Dispatch Through")).setStyle(col1style));
        receivingList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text(field("DispatchThrough", type.stringType()))).setStyle(col2style));
        ComponentColumnBuilder receivingColumn = col.componentColumn("", receivingList).setFixedWidth(137);

        VerticalListBuilder invoiceList = cmp.verticalList();
        invoiceList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text("Dated")).setStyle(col1style));
        invoiceList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text(field("InvoiceDate", type.stringType()))).setStyle(col2style));
        invoiceList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text("Mode/Terms of Payment")).setStyle(col1style));
        invoiceList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text(field("TermsofPayment", type.stringType()))).setStyle(col2style));
        invoiceList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text("Other Reference")).setStyle(col2style));

        invoiceList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text("Dated")).setStyle(col1style));
        invoiceList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text(field("BuyDate", type.stringType()))).setStyle(col2style));
        invoiceList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text("Dated")).setStyle(col1style));
        invoiceList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text(field("Dated", type.stringType()))).setStyle(col2style));
        invoiceList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text("Destination")).setStyle(col1style));
        invoiceList.add(cmp.horizontalList().add(cmp.text(field("Destination", type.stringType()))).setStyle(col2style));


        ComponentColumnBuilder invoiceColumn = col.componentColumn("", invoiceList).setFixedWidth(138);
                      report


        .columnHeader(//title of the report


              Components.text("Tax Invoice Cum Delivery Challan").setStyle(boldStyle).setFixedHeight(10)
              .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER))

             .columns(nameColumn)
             .columns(receivingColumn)
             .columns(invoiceColumn)

              .pageFooter(Components.pageXofY())//show page number on the page footer
              .setDataSource("SELECT companyName,branchLocationAddress,mobileNumber,landLineNumber,emailID,InvoiceNo,DeliveryNote,EsugamNo,InvoiceDate,TermsofPayment,OrganizationName,DeliveryAddress,PhoneNo,BuyerOrderNo,DispatchDocumentNo,DispatchThrough,BuyDate,Dated,Destination FROM marketing_database.company_profile,marketing_database.invoiceclient_details where invoiceclient_details.CId ='1'", 
                                      connection);

        try {
                    //show the report
            report.show();

                    //export the report to a pdf file
            report.toPdf(new FileOutputStream("c:/report.pdf"));
        } catch (DRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
```

As you can see in the pic the columns alignment is irregular. Now my questions if data in database is large and when it will fill the data into PDF,the alignment should be damaged. I mean three columns should come in the same line. Any help in this will be appreciated

Comment: It seems to me that you are mixing different entities and you are trying to get them displayed properly. You should design a layout first and then use frames and stretch types on the fields.

Comment: @tobi6 Do you have any example on how to set layout,stretch and frames

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know about the Java implementation.

Comment: @tobi6 Then how do implement that other than in java

Comment: Sorry, I just know about Jaspersoft Studio where the report will be designed.

Comment: @tobi6 one question is can jaspersoft studio provide the features of dynamic reports. i mean if a row is null. i dont want to print it and if there are any columns from the database that is added in the future.we can display them as well

Comment: @tobi6 what i mean was i used jaspersoft iReport Designer 5.6.0 but that is used to create static things. I mean we have to design everything and we have to send values to that.If some fields are null then it dont have to print the entire row .